# Is the RISC V source code available to the public (Where is the source code?)

Tags: cpu-architecture, riscv

I am a student and would like to know where the source code for RISC V is hosted at so I can learn and create my own 'architecture', with credits of course.

And my other question is that if the source code is inaccessible to the community, then how is it considered Open Source?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

RISC-V is an architecture (https://riscv.org/blog/2020/02/risc-v-is-not-an-open-source-processor-krste-asanovic-chairman-of-the-board-risc-v/) which is open and royalty-free to implement.  There are various implementations in VHDL or whatever (microarchitectures), including some open-source ones.  google found https://github.com/riscv/riscv-cores-list which lists various designs by license.  For example https://opencores.org/projects/biriscv.  AFAIK, the fully open-source ones are in-order, not super-wider or OoO exec.

TL:DR: there isn't "the source code" for RISC-V overall.

Unless you mean the LaTeX source for the ISA specification docs (https://riscv.org/technical/specifications/), in which case yes, that page (currently) even links to https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/tag/draft-20210805-4e220a3 which has "source code" .tar.gz and .zip links which I assume contain LaTeX or similar source the PDFs are built from.

An architecture / ISA is a paper specification that CPUs implement, and that software is written against.  It includes details like instruction encodings, and also memory ordering rules, exception handling, page table formats, etc.  All the rules that specify what happens.  But none of the internal implementation details.

You can modify that if you want, to customize the architecture e.g. by adding new instructions or new / different semantics for something, because RISC-V *is* open-source.  (And then design CPUs that implement it and write software for them)